# How to get cloned check box value

Tags: jquery

I have html code containing check boxes,i tried to get those values while cloned but i din't get properly.
Here is my html code:

```
 <div id="divHideMeds">
  <div class="copymeds">
     <div class="form-group">
        <label  class=" control-label col-md-3">Times to give</label>
          <div class="checkbox-list col-md-9">
             <label class="checkbox-inline">
                <input type="checkbox" id="breakfast" value="Breakfast"> Breakfast
             </label> 
             <label class="checkbox-inline">
                 <input type="checkbox" id="lunch" value="Lunch"> Lunch
             </label> 
              <label class="checkbox-inline">
                  <input type="checkbox" id="dinner" value="Dinner"> Dinner
              </label> 
             <label class="checkbox-inline">
                  <input type="checkbox" id="bed" value="Bed"> Bed
             </label> 
          </div>
       </div>
       <div class="add">
        <button type="button" id="abc">Add More</button>
     </div>
    </div>
 <div>
```

Here is my js code:

```
 $(".abc").click(function (e) {
    var cloned = $(".copymeds:first").clone(true).appendTo('#divHideMeds');
   });
```

i tried for getting those check box values like this:

```
 $('.copymeds').each(function () {
      arr.push({
         forBreakfast:$("#breakfast",this).val(),
         forLunch:$("#lunch",this).val(),
         forDinner:$("#dinner",this).val(),
         beforeBed:$("#bed",this).val(),
      });
});
```

Here i have problem with check boxes only remaining data will came perfectly.my problem is i am getting first clone values only but not get more than one clone data check box values.please help me how to get check box values data  if we have 2 more clones.

Answer (score 1):

You have duplicate IDs on your page (after cloning). Make sure you either make them unique (say, by adding index to each) or swithing them to classes. Then you'll be able to select more that one of each, otherwise it only selects the first (and which should be: the only!) of them.

```
     <label class="checkbox-inline">
        <input type="checkbox" id="breakfast" value="Breakfast"> Breakfast
     </label> 
     <label class="checkbox-inline">
         <input type="checkbox" id="lunch" value="Lunch"> Lunch
     </label> 
      <label class="checkbox-inline">
          <input type="checkbox" id="dinner" value="Dinner"> Dinner
      </label> 
     <label class="checkbox-inline">
          <input type="checkbox" id="bed" value="Bed"> Bed
     </label>
```

So, the problematic ones are: `breakfast`, `lunch`, `dinner` and `bed`. They all get cloned.

Comment: if i do like that i am getting one problem that is i have cancel button is there like add button.when i click on add button i implement the id's like(breakfast1,breakfast2).if i cancel one of these 2 and clicks on add (breakfst3) will came.so then how can i find these id's in js by using each function

Comment: You can modify your buttons to have onclick functions which will take the index as a parameter: `<button type="button" onclick="add(2)">Add More</button>` Here the index is 2, for example.

Comment: please give me an example for better understanding

Comment: Use an index variable to keep track of the current id index. Start with 1 and increase with every cloning you do. However, I think it would be much easier just to use classes.

Answer (score 0):

## try This

```
var div = $(".relation1:first").clone()
.appendTo("div.relationdiv");
div.find('select option:selected').attr('selected', false);
div.find("input").val("");
div.first().find("input radio:checked").prop('checked', true);
div.find('input:radio').attr('checked',false);
```

Comment: div:first is a object that copy to other button in div you use select option and radio button you you use this than we look not auto select option value....

Comment: add that into answer